# iOS 7 vs iOS 8 autolayout issue

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

There is an issue related to when autolayout constraints kick in when running code in iOS 7.1 vs iOS 8.4 I have failed to find any documentation related to it. (using Xcode 6.4 base SDK iOS 8.4)

So I have a `scrollview` with autoconstraints enforced to it. But these constraints kick in at different time when my `viewController` code is executed. From my personal understanding of autolayout, the behaviour in iOS 7.1 is the expected behaviour.

For iOS 7.1:
[image]

For iOS 8.4
[image]

Focusing on the y position of `scrollViewFrame`, y position being `114.0` is my expected behaviour from the start in `viewDidLoad` function but that only happens in iOS 7.1 
What could be the reason to it?

All these logs are called before/after the `super` functions using `print()` command in swift just to show you guys if there is any difference. Both logs are from iPhone 4s simultors

Comment: What is inside the `scrollView`? Something strange is going on with the initialization of the constraints, look also at `scrollViewContentSize`. Does the difference in behavior affect the final display?

Comment: @PietroSaccardi yea something is but that issue arises right after viewDidLoad itself. before i do any changes to contentView subviews or change content size

Comment: I see. It would be helpful to know (1) which constrains are defined in the xib (or in any custom code) (2) what is inside the `scrollView`, if any object (3) if the final visible layout actually differs. It's tricky to replicate otherwise.